# How to call my onchange event on zebra date picker?

Tags: javascript, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, zebra-ui-framework

I have used input type text field and attach zebra date picker to it, now how I can call my `function(updateDates())` on `onchange` event?

Without zebradatepicker I am able to use `updateDates()` function..

```
$('#tripDate1').val(formattedDate).attr("min", formattedDateMin).Zebra_DatePicker({ direction: 1 });  

<input id="tripDate1" style="margin-left: 3px;" type="text" onkeypress="return false" onkeydown="return false" onchange="updateDates(this.id)" />
```

Comment: Where is your code ? What Zebra ?

Comment: Have you tried with `onSelect` instead of `onChange`?

Answer (score 1):

Try with `onSelect` function and define it in Javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
$(function() {
        $('#tripDate1').datepicker( {
            onSelect: function() {
                updateDates(this.id);
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<input id="tripDate1" style="margin-left: 3px;" type="text" />
```

Comment: ouch, that's awful. bind with events instead of using `onkeypress`, `onkeydown`, etc... in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Zebra Datepicker has event listeners which includes the `onSelect`. See example below.

```
$(function() {
    $("#tripDate1").Zebra_DatePicker({
        format: 'm/d/Y', //Ensures format consistency
        onSelect: function() {
            //Call your update function here.
        }
    });
});
```